# Triangulation of $S^2 \times S^2 $

Tags: algebraic-topology, geometric-topology

Could someone tell me or give a reference for the minimal triangulation of $S^2\times S^2$ and $S^2\times S^1\times S^1$ ?

Thanks,

Comment: I'll be nicely surprised if they are known.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez   Do you mean it is very hard ? If delet minimal, just a triangulation of $S^2\times S^2$, is it  easy ?

Comment: @lanse7pty, finding a triangulation is trivial. From triangulations of spaces $X$ and $Y$ it is easy to construct a triangulation of $X\times Y$.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez  How to do it ? I am sorry for my lazy to read relative books , but if it is not complex, could you tell me how to construct the triangulation of  the product space.